# Javascript how to stop this one function

Tags: javascript

We have this function running. How do I prevent it from running in the browser?
I have a chrome extension to try and add some "fixes" and tweaks to a site and this is one function I want removed but how to override it?

```js
stripTags: function(e, t) {
            t = (((t || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join("");
            var n = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi
              , r = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
            return e.replace(r, "").replace(n, function(e, n) {
                return t.indexOf("<" + n.toLowerCase() + ">") > -1 ? e : ""
            })
        },
```

Comment: Can you access the object defining `stripTags`?

Comment: This is all I can see with StripTags other than the input fields that applies that function, some text boxes

Comment: Depends a lot on the context of `stripTags`. Can you post exactly where is it defined?

Comment: I cannot see any definition for `stripTags`
I found 12 occurrences and 11 of those are the fields where html tags will be stripped. For example:
`t && this.set("subject", _.stripTags(t));`

and

`s && this.set("inboundMessage", _.stripTags(s));`

the 12th is the one I posted above in the main post / question

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an empty function with the same name directly following it (trying to override it?)..

Comment: I don't have direct access to the file, I have a chrome extension with some tweaks to add things I want and in this case I want to remove this to prevent the html tags from being stripped on submission.

I tried doing 
`function striptags(){
//to block the function but it didn't work
}`

Comment: So can you try to add an empty function with the same name in the console after page load but prior to submission?  You'd have access to that and then when you submit your empty function should execute and not the other.

Comment: I added a function called stripTags to the document load but it doesn't override it for me. If I try `stripTags: function(e,t){  with nothing inside   }` i get syntax errors